# package error in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, package, packaging

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.utils.*;

public class SetTimeoutExample extends Sprite {
    private var delay:Number = 1000; // delay before calling myDelayedFunction

    public function SetTimeoutExample() {
        var intervalId:uint = setTimeout(myDelayedFunction, delay, "Hello", "World");
    }

    public function myDelayedFunction():void {
        trace(arguments[0] + " " + arguments[1]);
    }
}
}
```

i take an error about package what is wrong in this code?thanks

Comment: what is the error your'e getting?

Comment: post the error number and error message - is this code written in the file `SetTimeoutExample.as` - if not, that's the reason.

Comment: 1037: Package Cannot Be Nested. i write this in player.fla

Comment: amorghosh as you say,i guess i write it in a document class.i'm really new to as3.how can i add this.would you explain more please?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a new file called `SetTimeoutExample.as`, and put the code in there. Make sure that the file is in the same directory as `player.fla`. Then open player.fla, and in the properties window (Window > Properties), set the "Class" field to `SetTimeoutExample` (without the .as).

Comment: thanks very much but now i get a new error 1180:Call to a possibly undefined method addFrameScript.